# AVAudioPlayer.playing crash

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

So I have this save button and if I press it the current viewController dismisses and any sound that is playing should stop.

But it crashes as soon as I press the save button. What is the mistake in my code?

```
@IBAction func save(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    audioStopPlaying()
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func audioStopPlaying() {
    if model.audioPlayer.playing.boolValue == true {
        model.audioPlayer.stop()

    }
}
```

Model:

```
class Model: NSObject {

    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
}
```

Comment: Where does `model` come from?

Comment: Can you please provider more context? If you can include what the error says and what "model" is.

Comment: If it crash, is there an error message in the debug console? Not that `model.audioPlayer.playing` should already be a `bool`, so why the `boolValue` after it?

Comment: If I play a sound an press the button it stops and exits the viewController. But if the viewController appears and I don't play a sound and press save right away it crashes and gives me this error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x38) (lldb)